# Does 'ring' diaphragm reduce lens spherical abberations?

Tags: optics

As I see it, as light comes through approximately same angular area of the lens, it should have less aberrations, and at the same time, it should still have high θ -> diffraction limit should stay as without this diaphragm.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less spherical aberration, yes, but not less coma, nor less astigmatism.

The diffraction would look like on a telescope with a very important
central obstruction. It will not have the usual diffraction pattern, but
the diffraction-limited MTF will be bad for low spatial frequencies
(rapid decay of contrast) and then flatten out in such a way that the
ultimate resolution (extinction of contrast) will be the same as for the
full aperture.

**Edit:** I found this page with nice simulations of the effect of a
central obstruction on both the MTF and the images:

http://www.damianpeach.com/simulation.htm

Scroll down to "Part 2. Performance effects of different size central obstructions".
As you can see, although the resolution (at MTF = 0) is the same, the
image with 50% obstruction looks bad because of the loss of contrast at
mid and low frequencies.

Comment: If you want to see what this can look like, have a google for pictures taken with a 'reflex' telephoto lens (constructed using a curved reflector which blocks the center of the pupil.) They are light and have little chromatic aberration but very distinctive 'donut' bokeh effect.

Comment: @zephyr - these are called catadioptric/cassegrain lenses.

Comment: Hehe by chance I own Sony 500/8 Reflex ;-)